# Android talkback reads background text behind the bottomsheet

Tags: android, accessibility, bottom-sheet, talkback

When bottom sheet is shown in my app want to stop talkback reading background text. The behaviour works fine in Google News app.

Issue:

- Talkback setting is ON.
- Launch the app fragment is shown.
- Bottomsheet is shown on top of fragment covering half of the screen.
- Talkback reads background text first then reads bottomsheet text.

Fix I want is stop reading background text.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting android:importantForAccessibility="no" on this background view?

Comment: Yes, It worked after setting android:importantForAccessibility="no" and android:foucusable=true. I was just setting it at wrong place.